Using a Resource Dictionary in a Description Attribute C#
I am working on an app (WPF) that we need to have translatable to different languages, I am struggling to have the drop down translated when the language setting is changed.
It was agreed with my team that we would be using Resource Dictionaries, the one I am working on is building a list from an enum; I am using the Description attribute to show the value in the dropdown instead of the enum.  How can I get the value to be picked up from the Resource Dictionary?
I was thinking something like this:
[Description(Application.Current.Resources["Value to display"])]
but I know the description needs to be absolute, so I am assuming I need to write some sort of extension but I don't know what.  Any help would be appreciated.
[Description(Application.Current.Resources["Value to display"])]

Attribute parameter values must be able to be resolved completely at compile time. If you use an expression such as Application.Current.Resources["Value to display"], the compiler will not be able to resolve it.
What you need to do is to use the resource key as the attribute parameter, and then at runtime resolve it.
Description("Value to display")

To resolve it at runtime, you have two options:

Option 1: use reflection to identify the type with such attribute and then do things with the attribute parameter.

Option 2: create a source generator that will generate an extension method for the annotated class that will resolve the resource key to its value. The annotated class must be marked partial of course. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview .


